SImulation model and state space model giving different output
I am working on a power electronics project, and am facing a problem with simulink. I am trying to find the transfer function of a SEPIC converter using state space analysis method. I am able to calculate the transfer function using the state matrices A,B,C and D. I aim to verify if the matrices have been calculated correctly by running the simulation of the converter as well as the state space model in simulink. The converter model gives the correct expected output, but the state space model is giving incorrect output. Since the state space model should represent the converter in continuous manner, i expect both outut waveforms to be exactly the same, but it is not working that way.
I am attaching a picture of the simulation,simulation diagram
this is the code i am using in the script to calculate the matrices.
clc
clear

R = 30;
L1 = 0.34e-3;
L2 = 0.34e-3;
Cap1 = 0.010e-3;
Cap2 = 0.100e-3;
Vg = 24;
D = 5/7;

% syms R L1 L2 Cap1 Cap2 Vg D

A1 = [0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1/L2, 0; 0, -1/Cap1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, -1/(R*Cap2)];
A2 = [0, 0, -1/L1, -1/L1; 0, 0, 0, -1/L2; 1/Cap1, 0, 0, 0; 1/Cap2, 1/Cap2, 0, -1/(R*Cap2)];
B1 = [1/L1; 0; 0; 0];
B2 = [1/L1; 0; 0; 0];
C1 = [0, 0, 0, 1];
C2 = [0, 0, 0, 1];
D1 = 0;
D2 = 0;


As = A1*D + A2*(1 - D);
Bs = B1*D + B2*(1 - D);
Cs = C1*D + C2*(1 - D);
Ds = D1*D + D2*(1 - D);
U = [Vg];
X = -inv(As)*Bs*U


Ass = As
Bss = ((A1-A2)*X) + ((B1-B2)*U)
Css = Cs
Dss = Ds


[a,b] = ss2tf(Ass,Bss,Css,Dss);
H = tf(a,b)

step(H)

PID = pidtune(H, 'PID')


I have verified the state space model from the few sources that I could find it in like research papers. Also recalculated everything myself just to make sure i was not making a mistake but the result is exactly the same.
